# How to save image to camera folder in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I need to save an image to camera folder, but as Android Q getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated, I do it in another way.
What I have (this method receive bitmap and its name):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } else {
        String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME;

        File file = new File(imagesDir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }

        File image = new File(
                imagesDir,
                name + ".png"
        );

        final long fileHashCode = image.hashCode();
        Logger.d(TAG, "saveImage, saving image file, hashCode = " + fileHashCode);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

That perfectly works for all needed OS versions, but it looks inaccurate and I'd like to find a more common way. 
I tried to play around with content values or try some similar way as for Q, but it doesn't work. I've seen many questions here, but neither of them can help me.

The question is how can I optimize saving for OS lower than Q?

Comment: "but it looks inaccurate" -- it seems OK to me. On Q you might use `IS_PENDING` while you are writing out the content. "how can I optimize saving for OS lower than Q?" -- other than the `fileHashCode` pair of lines, what you have there seems reasonable.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so that's ok I save it in different ways? There's no way to save the image like for Q? I was looking for another URI for insert, but nothing.

Comment: "so that's ok I save it in different ways?" -- sure. "There's no way to save the image like for Q?" -- not in a specific location. `RELATIVE_PATH` did not exist prior to Q. Note that `MediaStore` will not know about your image right away in the older-than-Q branch of your code. If that is important to you, use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Please how we can get the path of the image saved on Android Q

Comment: @pic: Use the `Uri`, as there is no filesystem path that you can use. Glide, Picasso, and other good image-loading libraries can display images identified by a `MediaStore` `Uri`. Or, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the image bytes yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you so much, what about the path of the folder itself, I'm able to save image in Pictures/FolderName, I want to display all image saved in another activity

Comment: @pic: You would need to query `MediaStore`. If you have questions about this process, and you cannot find existing answers about it, please ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare ,I will ask for it, thank you so much

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The most generalized version I was able to write is:

```
private Uri saveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String folderName, @NonNull String fileName) throws IOException {
    OutputStream fos = null;
    File imageFile = null;
    Uri imageUri = null;

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            contentValues.put(
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + folderName);
            imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            if (imageUri == null)
                throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");

            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        } else {
            File imagesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + folderName);

            if (!imagesDir.exists())
                imagesDir.mkdir();

            imageFile = new File(imagesDir, fileName + ".png");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        }


        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos))
            throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
        fos.flush();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
    }
    
    if (imageFile != null) {//pre Q
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{imageFile.toString()}, null, null);
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    }
    return imageUri;
}
```

If you've found a better way, post here, I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: How can i display this image using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME

bcz it's not working in android 10

Comment: Can you please solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984396/save-txt-file-on-android-q

Comment: What is the `IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME` for? needs to be a custom folder name?

Comment: @RRGT19, optional folder name.

Comment: best solution I have seen

Answer (score 1):

Using this document : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

> Create temp file first

```
val mTempFileRandom = Random()

fun createTempFile(ext:String, context:Context):String {
  val path = File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "AppFolderName")
  if (!path.exists() && !path.mkdirs())
  {
    path = context.getExternalCacheDir()
  }
  val result:File
  do
  {
    val value = Math.abs(mTempFileRandom.nextInt())
    result = File(path, "AppFolderName-" + value + "-" + ext)
  }
  while (result.exists())
  return result.getAbsolutePath()
}
```

> Send file from path

```
copyFileToDownloads(this@CameraNewActivity, File(savedUri.path))
```

> Copy data to storage

> MAIN_DIR: Main folder name in which you want to store image (Like App Name)
> IMAGE_DIR: Sub folder if you want to create.

```
    fun copyFileToDownloads(context: Context, downloadedFile: File): Uri? {

    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_SAVE_IMAGE).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_$timeStamp.jpg"
    val resolver = context.contentResolver

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageFileName)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, IMAGE_MIME_TYPE)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + MAIN_DIR + File.separator + IMAGE_DIR + File.separator)
        }

        resolver.run {
            val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

            uri
        }
    } else {
        val authority = "${context.packageName}.provider"
        val imagePath =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.absolutePath
        val destinyFile = File(imagePath, imageFileName)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, destinyFile)
        FileUtils.scanFile(context, destinyFile.absolutePath)

        uri
    }?.also { uri ->
        var writtenValue = 0L
        // Opening an outputstream with the Uri that we got
        resolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
            downloadedFile.inputStream().use { inputStream ->
                writtenValue = inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                Log.d("Copy Written flag", " = $writtenValue")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ScanFile : ( More detail : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection )

```
fun scanFile(context:Context, path:String) {
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                                  arrayOf<String>(path), null,
                                  { newPath, uri-> if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                   Log.e("TAG", "Finished scanning " + newPath) })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't we use media store for above and below Android Q?
I have tried following way and it is working fine.

```
private fun writeImage() {
    val uri =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } else {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        }

    val imageDetail = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpeg")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }
    }
    val contentUri = contentResolver.insert(uri, imageDetail)

    contentUri?.let {
        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "w", null).use { pd ->
            pd?.let {
                /* val fos = FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)
                   val array = getBitmapToBase64()
                   fos.write(array, 0, array.size)
                   fos.close() 
                */
                // or
                // Your logic to write an Image file.
            }
        }

        imageDetail.clear()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            imageDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            contentUri.let { contentResolver.update(it, imageDetail, null, null) }
        }

        // open the saved image file with gallery app
        Snackbar.make(
            findViewById(android.R.id.content), "saved", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        ).setAction("Show") {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contentUri)
            startActivity(intent)
        }.show()

    } ?: Toast.makeText(this, "not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```