# In Android Nougat and Later versions, can't we store image/video in Public directories? If we can, how to we write code compatible with old versions?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery, mediastore, android-fileprovider

I want to save image to public Pictures directory and then share it with other apps. For this :

- I checked Android docs ([FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) and [Setting Up File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)).
- I also checked many StackOverflow questions.

but they only talk about saving file to our package's storage area.

I want to write code which would be compatible from API 16(Jelly Bean 4.1) to latest API 30(R). Code which I wrote work fluently below Nougat. I know I need to use `FileProvidr`, `<provider>` and `<path>`. But how to save image to Public Pictures folder?

Should I have to use `MediaStore`, `ContentPRovider`, `ContentValues` API?

When we should use `FileProvider` and when we should use `MediaStore`?

Comment: You can write your files to the public directories. In the same way you write them to app specific or app private locations.

Comment: old method not works in Nougat+ and `<path>` give links of `/data/data/<package-name>/...`

Comment: Best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357175/how-to-save-image-to-camera-folder-in-android-q/57357571#57357571 Some other nice answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904485/how-to-save-an-image-in-android-q-using-mediastore